Deeper contextual understanding of Isaiah 66:5 (c1 & c2) ‘Let the LORD be glorified, that we may see your joy.’

Isaiah 66:5


New Living Translation
(a) Hear this message from the LORD, all you who tremble at his words:
(b) “Your own people hate you and throw you out for being loyal to my name.
(c1) ‘Let the LORD be honored!’ they scoff.
(c2) ‘Be joyful in him!’
(d) But they will be put to shame.


English Standard Version
(a) Hear the word of the LORD, you who tremble at his word:
(b) “Your brothers who hate you and cast you out for my name’s sake have said,
(c1) ‘Let the LORD be glorified,
(c2) that we may see your joy’;
(d) but it is they who shall be put to shame.


NASB 1995
(a) Hear the word of the LORD, you who tremble at His word:
(b) “Your brothers who hate you, who exclude you for My name’s sake, Have said,
(c1) ‘Let the LORD be glorified,
(c2) that we may see your joy.’
(d) But they will be put to shame.


New King James Version
(a) Hear the word of the LORD, You who tremble at His word:
(b) “Your brethren who hated you, Who cast you out for My name’s sake, said,
(c1) ‘Let the LORD be glorified,
(c2) That we may see your joy.’
(d)  But they shall be ashamed.”


66:5
The Westminster Leningrad Codex
5 שִׁמְעוּ֙ דְּבַר־יְהוָ֔ה הַחֲרֵדִ֖ים אֶל־דְּבָר֑וֹ אָמְרוּ֩
אֲחֵיכֶ֨ם שֹׂנְאֵיכֶ֜ם מְנַדֵּיכֶ֗ם לְמַ֤עַן שְׁמִי֙ יִכְבַּ֣ד יְהוָ֔ה
וְנִרְאֶ֥ה בְשִׂמְחַתְכֶ֖ם וְהֵ֥ם יֵבֹֽשׁוּ׃

I'm trying to get a deeper contextual understanding of the meaning and purpose behind the Isaiah 66:5 (c) bible verse fragment.
( By the way, here is a url link to the biblehub commentaries: https://biblehub.com/commentaries/isaiah/66-5.htm  , however, I was Not satisfied with a lot of the commentaries. )
First impression is that the Isaiah 66:5 (c1) bible verse fragment seems  that contemporary Nonbelievers of the biblical God's people who are insultingly taunting God's people.
To elaborate, said Nonbelievers will cast out and//or reject God's people thinking that God is being glorified due to said actions.
However, for most of the translations, when one contextually tries to understand Isaiah 66:5 (c1 and c2), it seems a strange because why would God's people feel joy when they themselves are cast out or rejected.
Another interpretation is to view Isaiah 66:5 (c1 and c2) as a sarcastic comment but in my opinion, it does Not make sense as a sarcastic statement.
Furthermore, it's strange that the New Living Translation (NLT) separates Isaiah 66:5 (c1) and  Isaiah 66:5 (c2) as 2 different comments.
To elaborate,  Isaiah 66:5 (c1) could be seen as a comment by Nonbelievers insultingly taunting God's people by indicating that the casting out and/or rejection of God's people will bring the Lord glory.
Isaiah 66:5 (c2) comment could be seen as the prophet Isaiah encouraging God's people to be joyful  because the Nonbelievers will be put to shame.
However, I'm skeptical about the accuracy NLT translation in relation to the original Hebrew scriptures because None of the other bible translations separate  Isaiah 66:5 (c1) and  Isaiah 66:5 (c2) as 2 different comments.
Could someone please respond with an deeper contextual explanation Isaiah 66:5 (c1 and c2) within the larger context of Isaiah 66:5? (Please take into consideration the original Hebrew in the response)

Let's begin from Isaiah 66:2-4

2 Has not my hand made all these things,
and so they came into being?”
declares the Lord.
“These are the ones I look on with favor:
those who are humble and contrite in spirit,
and who tremble at my word.
3 But whoever sacrifices a bull
is like one who kills a person,
and whoever offers a lamb
is like one who breaks a dog’s neck;
whoever makes a grain offering
is like one who presents pig’s blood,
and whoever burns memorial incense
is like one who worships an idol.
They have chosen their own ways,
and they delight in their abominations;
4 so I also will choose harsh treatment for them
and will bring on them what they dread.
For when I called, no one answered,
when I spoke, no one listened.
They did evil in my sight
and chose what displeases me.” (NIV)
5 Hear the word of the Lord,
you (the righteous) who tremble at his word:
“Your own people (the oppressor, wicked) who hate you,
and exclude you because of my name, have said,
‘Let the Lord be glorified,
that we may see your joy!’
Yet they (the oppressor, wicked) will be put to shame.

Isaiah 66:2-4 depicts two kinds of people: those who tremble at the Lord's word and find favor with Him, and those who do evil in His sight.
Isaiah observed the leaders and wealthy people of Israel oppressing the poor and living in luxury, while the faithful and just suffer (Isaiah 3:14-15; 5:8). This theme recurs throughout his book, highlighting the need for righteousness and justice as called for by the Lord.
In the last chapter, Isaiah 66, the Lord responds to the righteous, acknowledging their currently suffering. Despite receiving sarcastic wishes (Isaiah 66:5c1&c2) of their wicked brothers, the final judgment will bring shame upon the wicked.
Taking Isaiah 66:5c1&c2 at face value, it is the wicked challenging the righteous, saying "Where is your God who can save you from suffering?" The meaning remains the same, regardless of whether the sentence is broken in the NLT or not in other versions.

Isa 66 takes up the same theme as Isa 1 concerning sincerity of worship.  That is, the prophet is making a sharp distinction between:

going through the motions" of offering sacrifices, etc
vs sincerely being dedicated to worshiping and truly loving God.

Jeremiah had the same burden when he writes (Jer 7:4-7)

Do not trust in deceptive words, chanting:
‘This is the temple of the LORD,
the temple of the LORD,
the temple of the LORD.’
For if you really correct your ways and deeds, if you act justly
toward one another, if you no longer oppress the foreigner and the
fatherless and the widow, and if you no longer shed innocent blood in
this place or follow other gods to your own harm, then I will let you
live in this place, in the land that I gave to your fathers forever
and ever.

Back to Isa 66.
The context to that which follows is given in V1 & 2

V1 & 2a states the greatness and majesty of God
V2b states this:


“This is the one I will esteem: he who is humble and contrite in
spirit, who trembles at My word."


V3 essentially says that without a sincere love for God, all the religious ceremonies are meaningless, as stated in Isa 1:11-17.  See also Ps 40:6-8, 51:16, 17, 1 Sam 15:22, Hos 6:6, Prov 15:8, 21:3, Jer 6:20, Micah 6:6-8, etc.  Note especially the famous passage in Micah 6:6-8 -


With what shall I come before the LORD when I bow before the God on
high? Should I come to Him with burnt offerings, with year-old calves?
Would the LORD be pleased with thousands of rams, with ten thousand
rivers of oil? Shall I present my firstborn for my transgression, the
fruit of my body for the sin of my soul?
He has shown you, O man, what is good. And what does the LORD require
of you

but to act justly,
to love mercy,
and to walk humbly with your God?


In Isa 66:5 - the enemies who realize and recognize false piety are seen to be mocking the Jew's pretense using the forms and ceremonies they had.  Jesus made the same observations in Matt 23!!

I can't pretend to know more than the translators who seem to be all over the map on this question. However here is some important context:

3 The one slaughtering an ox, striking a man,
sacrificing a lamb, breaking a dog’s neck, Making an offering of pig’s blood,
burning incense, honoring an idol— These have chosen their own ways,
and taken pleasure in their own abominations. 4 I in turn will choose affliction for them
and bring upon them what they fear. Because when I called, no one answered,
when I spoke, no one listened. Because they did what was evil in my sight,
and things I do not delight in they chose,

The above verses describe "the ones who hate you" in Isaiah 66:5b. The question then becomes: is 66:5c

a sincere quote by "the ones who hate you"
a sarcastic quote by them
a hope expressed by the prophet that these haters will repent and honor God.

I suggest that while NLV goes too far by declaring that  ‘Let the LORD be glorified, that we may see your joy’ is a jest, it may be right that this was the intent of those who said it. We have other verses that take this approach. For example:
Psalm 22

7 All they that see Me laugh Me to scorn; they shoot out their lip,
they shake their head, saying, 8 “He trusted in the Lord that He would
deliver him; let Him deliver him, seeing He delighted in him!” KJ21

Conclusion: Given that enemies sometimes mocked God's faithful ones by praying for them sarcastically, it is certainly possible that this is the intent in the verses cited in the OP. It is possible that ‘Let the LORD be glorified, that we may see your joy’ is a comment by the author. But it makes more sense that this blessing is uttered sarcastically by scoffers.
